# How to code a query to connect to my server if I am using different devices with public ip

Tags: mysql, string, connection-string

I have a server in which I use this string to connect:

`string Cadena = "Server=10.10.10.10;Port=3306;Database=base;Uid=usuario;Pwd=pass;default command timeout=20000;Pooling=false;";`

I want to connect to my server using a public ip like this way `string Cadena = "Server=11.11.11.11;Port=3306;Database=base;Uid=usuario;Pwd=pass;default command timeout=20000;Pooling=false;";`

I just want to see if there are options  to do it. It is not transferring data and I do not want to use a VPN but if it is the only way to do it, I will have to. So, please give me ideas, what to search or something.

Comment: You'll need to forward port 3306 to your internal computer at 10.10.10.10 in your router. Although, it's ill advised to expose your database to the internet. A VPN on your network or an SSH tunnel (with port 22 forwarded to the server) with `-L 3306:localhost:3306` would be a safer option.

Comment: Thank you, I will look for info about it